# Testing a Windows Azure web app for maximum user load

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I am conducting some research on emerging web technologies and have created a very simple Azure website which makes use of web sockets and mongo db as the database. I have managed to get all the components working together and now must perform load testing on the application.

The main criteria is the maximum user load that the app can support, at the moment there is 1 web role instance, so probably I would need to test the max user load for that instance, then try with 2 instances and so on.

I found some solutions online such as Loadstorm, however I cannot afford to pay to use these services so I need to be able to do this from my own development machine OR from another cloud service.

I have come across Visual Studio Load Tests and they seem quite useful, however it seems they require VS Ultimate and an active msdn subscription - the prerequisites are listed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120818100009/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh674494.aspx). Also, from [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Load-testing-applications-in-Visual-Studio) which shows the basics of load tests, it seems like these load tests are created completely separately from the actual web project, so does that mean I can only see metrics related to the user? i.e. I cannot see the amount of RAM being used, processor etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might create a Linux virtual machine in Azure itself or another hosting provider and use [ApacheBench](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench) (ab) or [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to do simple load testing on your application. Be aware that in such a setup your benchmark servers may be a bottleneck themselves.

Another approach is to use online load testing services wich allow some free usage, such as:

- [loader.io](http://loader.io/), by SendGrid Labs
- [LoadStorm](http://loadstorm.com/)
- [Blazemeter](http://blazemeter.com)
- [Blitz](http://blitz.io)
- [Neotys](http://www.neotys.com/)
- [Loadimpact](http://loadimpact.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out loader.io it looks interesting!

Answer (score 3):

For load-testing, LoadStorm is very reasonably priced, especially compared to on-premises software (and has a free tier with up to 25 virtual clients). You can install code such as jmeter, but you'll still need machines (or vm's) to host and run it from, and you need to make sure that the load-generator machines aren't the bottleneck in your tests.

When you run your tests, you may want to consider separating your web tier from MongoDB. MongoDB will consume as much memory as possible (as that's what gives MongoDB its speed). In a real-world scenario, you'll likely have MongoDB in its own environment. So for your tests, I'd consider offloading MongoDB to its own instance(s), and 10gen has a [Worker Role setup](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/deploy-mongodb-worker-roles-in-azure/) that's fairly straightforward to install.

Also remember that NIC bandwidth is 100Mbps per core, which could be a limiting factor on your tests, depending on how much load you're driving.

One alternative to self-hosting MongoDB: Offload MongoDB to a hoster such as MongoLab. This will allow you to test the capacity of your web app without worrying about the details around MongoDB setup, configuration, optimization, etc. Currently MongoLab offers their free tier hosted in Azure, US West and US East data centers.

Comment: Thanks for the input! p.s. I do use the worker roles for MongoDB, in fact the overall aim is to test the viability of a website built with azure, mongodb and websockets :)

Answer (score 1):

Editing my response, didnt read the question carefully.

Check out this thread for various tools and links:
[Open source Tool for Stress, Load and Performance testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507683/open-source-tool-for-stress-testing-load-testing-and-performance-testing)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding the performance counters of the application under test you can revisit some of the latest features added to Visual Load Cloud base load test.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/07/get-application-performance-data-during-load-runs-with-visual-studio-online.aspx

To get more info on Visual Studio Cloud Load Testing solution - https://www.visualstudio.com/features/vso-cloud-load-testing-vs